# git add -A doesn't seem to work, have to manually do git rm ../../file.name

Tags: git

I did:

```
git add -A
```

so that all my updates would be ready for commit, but for some reason it says that I have to manually do a `git rm` for each file that was deleted before I can commit the changes.

why is that, I thought `git add -A` did everything in terms of adding any new files, deleting old ones, etc. (getting them ready for commit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the title of your question, I see that git says that `../../file.name` needs to be git-deleted. So it seems that you did the `git add` in a directory two levels below the one that holds `file.name`. However, this won't work. `git add` works on the current directory and directories below that one, not in directories higher up in the hierarchy. Unless you specify a path, of course.

Update:

This **is** documented, although the hint is a bit hidden. From `man git-add`:

> A, --all
>
> Update files that git already knows
>   about (same as --update) and add all
>   untracked files that are not ignored
>   by .gitignore mechanism.

and

> -u, --update
>
> Update only files that git already
>   knows about, staging modified content
>   for commit and marking deleted files
>   for removal. This is similar to what
>   "git commit -a" does in preparation
>   for making a commit, except that the
>   update is limited to paths specified
>   on the command line. **If no paths are
>   specified, all tracked files in the
>   current directory and its
>   subdirectories** are updated.

Comment: ah ok, I am not 100% i was in the parent path but that sounds like it was the case.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run the command in the root of the repository?

Answer (score 0):

These files you can commit using `git commit -a`. See [git-commit documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html).